# Keep the remaining value after subtract in php while loop

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, while-loop

I want to update three invoice data that belongs to a customer like below:

```
function updateInvoice($dbh, $id, $amount, $bal, $payer){
$q = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `zinvoice` WHERE `id`='$id' 
                  AND `status` IN ('Balance','Not Paid')");
$nrow = count($q->fetchAll());
$remain = 0;
if($nrow==1){
    //update the amount
    if($amount>$bal){
        $remain = $amount-$bal;
        $dbh->query("UPDATE zinvoice SET paidamount=(paidamount+$bal),
                     balanceamount='0', status='Paid'
                     WHERE id='$id'");
        //payment history update
    }else if($amount==$bal){
        $remain = 0;
        $dbh->query("UPDATE zinvoice SET paidamount=(paidamount+$bal),
                     balanceamount='0', status='Paid'
                     WHERE id='$id'");
        //payment history update
    }else{
        $newbal = $bal-$amount;
        $dbh->query("UPDATE zinvoice SET paidamount=(paidamount+$amount),
                     balanceamount='$newbal', status='Balance'
                     WHERE id='$id'");
        $remain = 0;
        //payment history update
    }
}else{
    //Nothing to update Because there is no Invoice with balance or not paid
} 
return $remain;
```

}

Now I want to update multiple invoices by a customer id=2. Customer with id=2 has three invoices with total amount of 1500, invoice id=1 has amount=500, invoice id=2 has amount=700, invoice id=3 has amount=300

```
 //Loop to update
  $q = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM zinvoice WHERE customerid='$cid'");

  while($row =$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):
    $remain = updateInvoice($dbh, $row->id, $amount, $row->balanceamount, $payer);
    if($remain>=1){
        updateInvoice($dbh, $row->id, $remain, $row->balanceamount, $payer);
    }else{
        //nothing
    }
endwhile;

$amount would come from a form//amount = 800
$cid would also come from a form//cid = 2
$payer would also come from a form//payer = john
```

The problem is that this code updated all the invoices to `status=Paid`. I want this code to update `Invoice id=2` which has balance amount=700 and as there would be 100 amount remaining, it will continue to update the other invoices, say `Invoice id=3`. But `Invoice id=3` has a balance `amount=300`, which is more than `100 amount`, it will subtract `100`from it and `Invoice id=3` would have `200 balance amount`. And there are no more amount left and would stop updating.

How would I achieve my desired output?

Note: I am not using prepared statement to avoid more codes here. And this code would be vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! I saw that you noted this, but don't know why you're not using prepared statements.

Comment: `SELECT id FROM zinvoice WHERE id='1' 
                      AND status='Balance'` shouldn't that use the real `id`, `$id`?

Comment: pdo is nice when u are using it correctly

Comment: @JayBlanchard, The problem is not in the Little Bobby thing. It is in the question. I have to write more codes if I use prepared here. So to avoid it, I used the normal query which of course is vulnerable to injection.

Comment: Why have the PHP do the math/comparison? Just have one query and have mysql set the status based on the value in the row. Also per your function call `updateInvoice($dbh, $res->id, 800,` your `$amount` is always 800, not 100.

Comment: @chris85, that's exactly my problem. how can I make the 800 not always 800? I need the math stuff here. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @ZoneSecurity Put the real value in function's call, in your `while` loop. I don't know where the amount comes from but you have a static value currently.

Comment: @chris85, the value will come from a form.

Comment: So use the form value, not the static, `$_POST['field_name']`.

Comment: The loop updates all the three rows because it is looping as long as there are rows with that specified customer id=2. On the first loop, I want to put the remaining amount after updates in a variable and I want to use that variable on the second loop to update on the specified condition. It is not working with my code.